# Android ViewPager with results from MySQL

Tags: android, mysql, android-viewpager

I want to create a ViewPager with results from MySQL database.

I Have found a tutorial which explain how to do it with one result (one TextView updated per page) : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JqFkkXMwWDg
But I want to have a ViewPager which displays a whole Layout (with several TextView) where the texts displayed are from my MySQL database.

What I want to do is like fill an activity Layout with texts from my MySQL database. The difference is that it's not activity Layouts, but page(fragment) Layouts.

Comment: If you know how to work with fragments then you need to create your XML layout file as needed to show your multiple textviews and then just populate the textviews with the data you need from your MySQL database.

Comment: i know how do do it on activity, but i don't know how to do it on fragments with the method instantiateItem

Comment: After you inflate your view for the fragment you can access the the XML elements from the view and set the text for which ever one you need to, for example `View mainFragmentView = inflate(layout_here,null,false) mainFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.textView1).setText(database_data_here);` similarly to that

Comment: Ok i try that ! seems to be a good answer :) Thanks !